# How to deal with flawed line geometries in Geopandas?

Tags: qgis, geopandas

I have a big dataset containing line-geometries. I would like to delete overlapping lines using the `intersection` statement in geopandas `overlay` in the following manner:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df1 = gpd.GeoSeries([LineString([(1,1), (0,2), (0,5), (0,6)]),LineString([(9,9), (10,12)])])
df2 = gpd.GeoSeries([LineString([(0,4), (0,7), (0,9), (0,12)]),LineString([(14,20), (13,13)])])
                               
df1a = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': df1, 'df1':[1,2], 'Class':1})
df2a = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': df2, 'df2':[1,2], 'Class':2})


overlay = gpd.overlay(df2a,df1a, how='difference')
```

But it seems some lines do not intersect, maybe they are lying on a very small scale not on each other but parallel, indicated by checking with:

```
line1[['geometry']].intersects(line2[['geometry']]) --> False
```

[image]

How can I fix the geometry, so that all lines in my dataset are pefectly aligned (Make parallel overlap), that I can run the Set-Operation ? Preferably I would like to have a solution in python (Geopandas), but in worst case also QGIS would be ok.

Comment: Please decide which software/language you're going to use, otherwise it's a bit too broad to answer it fully.

Comment: Dear Erik, please have a look at the last sentence. Preferably I'd like to have a solution in Python.

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly.